# Hierarchical data storage for read intensive application

Tags: database, tree, hierarchical-data, graph-databases

I'm trying to save a tree like hierarchy (data comes in json) to my database. I'm trying to decide what database technology and technique to use for read efficiency of the data.

[image]

1. All nodes in one level have the same schema (all nodes in one level in the tree have the same set of attributes)
2. Nodes in different levels in the tree do not have the same schema.
   So the same color implies the same type (see fig).
3. The tree structure Root -> A -> B -> D doesn't hold true all the time. Some times I get root node directly having child node type of D. Or node of type A having child of type D.
4. Leaf nodes can either be type B or D. The tree can never stop at level A, or root.
5. I will be storing around 700 nodes in the tree.

I wanted to represent this data in some database. I will write this once but read it multiple times.

Reading queries will be something like - give me the children of B3; or give me grand-grand children (Type D) of the root node...etc.
What/how would be the most efficient way of storing this data?

Comment: You are basically tagging a few possible databases here and wanting to ask people "which is better". This is off-topic and no-one reputable will respond. Therefore you are wasting your time. If you want a real response, then post separately to each community "separately" to find out what benefits you get from that platform based on a particular problem. And also make it less broad. Your question in this form is otherwise destined for closure. Some may take offence an downvote heavily as well.

Comment: Because you can change the layer for D1 and B5 to one layer up then technically the letter is not a layer.  Seems like the letter attribute is not a layer but an attribute.  Why are you considering the letter to be a layer?

Comment: @BlakesSeven - you have a good point. I'll post it to communities separately.

Comment: Well. @JoseMartinez you brought an interesting question. I made them on separate layers because the attributes in B5 are the same as in the other B's and all D's have the same set off attributes. B5 belongs to the B-class and D1 belongs to the D-class (has the same attribute set). Majority of the data follows Root -> A -> B -> C -> D pattern but there are few out-liers as in the root directly pointing to an object of type B. Or node of type A jumping and connecting to object of type D.

Comment: To closers: To me it appears that this question is about data structures and algorithms, not the choice of a DBMS. Thus, the question should not be closed. If it does not fit here, it should be moved to CS or Software Engineering.